# (Java text processing) Sorting text method and results in null?

Tags: java, sorting, io, text-processing

I am trying to make my own text binary sorting method, although I successfully compile it, it doesn't really finish the sorting job and returns null value. May anyone help pointing out the problem? Thanks a lot!!

`class mergesort{`

```
//main method
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

    String [] words = readWords(args[0]);

    long t1 = new Date().getTime();
    mergesort(words);
    long t2 = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("execution time:" + (t2 - t1) + " milliseconds");

    prWords(words);
}

//method for reading file
public static String [] readWords(String fn)throws IOException{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fn));
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder allwords = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){
        String [] items = line.trim().split("\\s+");
        allwords.append(convertCase(items[0])+"\t");
        }
        br.close();
        return allwords.toString().split("\t");
}

//Convert Case method
public static String convertCase(String n){ 

        String firstWd = n;         
        firstWd = n.charAt(0) + n.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        return firstWd;
}

public static String [] sortedWs = {};
public static void mergesort(String [] Ws){
    sortedWs = new String[Ws.length];
    mergesort(Ws, 0, Ws.length);
}

public static void mergesort(String [] Ws, int bgn, int end){
    if (end - bgn == 1) return;
    int mid = (bgn+end)/2;
    mergesort(Ws, bgn, mid);
    mergesort(Ws, mid, end);
    merge(Ws, bgn, end);
}

public static void merge(String [] Ws, int bgn, int end){

    int mid = (bgn+end)/2;
    int b1 = bgn;
    int b2 = end;

    int x = 0;

    while (b1 < mid && b2 < end) {
        if (Ws[b1].compareTo(Ws[b2]) <= 0){
            sortedWs[x] = Ws[b1]; b1++; x++;
        } else {
            sortedWs[x] = Ws[b2]; b2++; x++;
        }
    }
    //copy the rest
    if (b1 >= mid)
        while (b2 < end) { sortedWs[x] = Ws[b2]; b2++; x++; }
    if (b2 >= end)
        while (b1 < mid) { sortedWs[x] = Ws[b1]; b1++; x++; }

    for(int i = 0; i < end-bgn; i++) {
        Ws[bgn+i] = sortedWs[i];
    }

}

public static void prWords(String [] strs){

    for (String x : strs){
    System.out.println(x);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line in `merge()`:

```
    int b2 = end;
```

I believe it should be:

```
    int b2 = mid;
```

With this change a couple of test runs give the correct result on my computer.

Comment: That’s common for most of us. :-) At a point you’ll learn to use a debugger, that’s a great tool for sorting out such little errors (and bigger ones too).